# query in mongoid search in multiple condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

my model is like this

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
    self.full_text_search(search)
    else
    scoped
    end
   end
```

But i need to add this also

```
 self.or({start_date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i},{end_date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i})
```

in 
above search . How could i join this two condition in my above search. This two query works fine independently. But i need to make them join together. Any help with working example is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join two mongoid criterias by using the merge method:

```
q1 = self.scope
q2 = self.or(...)

result = q1.merge(q2)
```

Here is the relevant documentation:

http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Criteria#merge-instance_method

Comment: working example with above code will be more helpful. I tried but error

Comment: http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Criteria#merge-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
    q1 = self.full_text_search(search)
    q2 = self.or({start_date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i},{end_date: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i})
    result = q1.merge(q2)
    return result
    else
    scoped
    end
   end
```

THis is what i did and it is solved. Thanks @cpuguy83